# WAN connection is too slow on GCP compute instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

Yesterday I launched a new GCP instance which has about 15G RAM and 4CPU, I found Internet speed on the server is very slow! so I though to measure speed using speedtest-cli and found the connection is too slow, my mobile phone has a better Internet speed,
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Bridge-Telecom, Ltd (Yakutsk) [8129.74 km]: 471.518 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 7.72 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 3.06 Mb
The location of server is in SG, so I though to create another VM in Mumbai and test out, same result! GCP support costly so I can't connact them, can anybody explain to me what may be the issue? 
I chose default GCP Centos 8 image for these VM and didn't modify anything and chose premium network!

Answer (score 1):

Google does not have any control over ISP network and other factors involved (eg: routing etc.) over internet traffic, Google cannot guarantee the egress throughput for the egress network traffic from a virtual machine over the ISP network.

However, As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#network-performance), "All caps are meant as maximum possible performance between two VM instances in the same zone, both using [internal IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#networkaddresses)." I verified running two instances running Centos 8 with 4vCPU and 15GB RAM in same zone (SG) using the "iperf" 1 & 2 (yum install iperf) and received 9.56 Gbits/sec.

```
On the GCE VM machine (with iperf install) in the same zone, run the 
command:
iperf -s 

On egress test GCE VM machine (with iperf install) run the command 
iperf -c xx.xx.xx.xx     (where xx.xx.xx.xx is internal IP of the other VM-instance)

output:
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec  1.11 GBytes  9.56 Gbits/sec  6604    241 KBytes
```

as bandwidth which is very close to 10 Gbps as defined in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#network-performance). I would suggest you to verify the same.

[1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#network-performance) https://iperf.fr/

[2](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#networkaddresses) https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/diagnosing-network-speed-with-iperf

Comment: I think you may missed my point, WAN traffic on the VM instances it self should be Google GCP issue, can you work on a server if it's WAN connection is only about 3Mbits? I can't host even a simple web site on this speed, what usage would be useful for a VM that has a very low Internet speed?

Comment: please provide me the output of the following commands:

1] I see you're reaching to Bridge Telecom LLC server so, please list all the servers and look for the [Bridge Telecom LLC server](https://ipinfo.io/AS200988).

Example:
speedtest-cli --list | grep 200988 or speedtest-cli --list | grep Bridge Telecom LLC

2] Run the speedtest with server.
Example:
speedtest-cli -server 200988

Comment: You can add the outputs in your main question for more community visibility.

Comment: Hi Dany, I just replied as an answer since comment size is small for what I wrote, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests on GCP instances "same instance size and image" in Mumbai, SG.Europe and USA, I had good speed results with instances in USA and Europe and high slowness in SG and Mumbai, so seems some Asia zones have issues with Internet and WAN connections speed, I think since Corona virus issue Internet speed all over the world is suffering because most people are working from home or watching movies and play games, so Internet in my country and in most countries "I think" have difficulties.
I talked to one of my friends in SG and he has a connection of 1Gbits and for the first time in his history with Internet speed he finds Internet is slow nowadays!. 
so for my issue I replaced instance which was in SG and Mumbai with other in Europe and now my problem has been solved! also thanks for taking care and replying.